# How can I send and retrieve data with parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, progress-bar, data-retrieval

I wrote that code to send data to parse.com then to receive it also but I can't even send it till now, why ?!! I don't know the main reason, I put the internet and network permission in AndroidManifest.xml the parse class in application also in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mkadaimtwo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.mkadaimtwo.ParseCode"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and also put the parse class in application also in AndroidManifest.xml and that two codes of class and main Activity

ParseCode class Activity :

```
package com.example.mkadaimtwo;

import com.parse.Parse;

import android.app.Application;

public class ParseCode extends Application {
public void onCreate() {
      Parse.initialize(this, "GIuhlGILKRd8itvCF79femTyReHM6XjVkrfLKm3X",   "Fjg4tBrMgl0mY47K4kCL7hVmXhu8FmkE2on9PlXK");
    }
  }
```

the MainActivity Code :

```
package com.example.mkadaimtwo;

   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.net.ParseException;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;

   import com.parse.GetCallback;
   import com.parse.ParseObject;
   import com.parse.ParseQuery;

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText etCompanyName,etAddress,etNumberOfEmployees,etContactNumber;
ProgressDialog pd,pd2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etCompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCompanyName);
    etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    etNumberOfEmployees = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumberOfEmployees);
    etContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContactNumber);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setTitle("wait");
    pd.setMessage("by7aml elmafrod");
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setCancelable(true);


    pd2 = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd2.setTitle("wait");
    pd2.setMessage("by7aml elmafrod");
    pd2.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd2.setCancelable(true);

    //here we will Load the old company data from Parse.com

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestBosyApp");
    query.getInBackground("ijy1qi78g8", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject testBosyApp, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                String companyName = testBosyApp.getString("company_name");
                String address = testBosyApp.getString("address");
                String numberOfEmployees = testBosyApp.getString("number_of_employees");
                String contactNumber = testBosyApp.getString("contact_number");

                etCompanyName.setText(companyName);
                etAddress.setText(address);
                etNumberOfEmployees.setText(numberOfEmployees);
                etContactNumber.setText(contactNumber);

                pd.dismiss();


            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder mDialoge = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
                mDialoge.setTitle("Erorr");
                mDialoge.setMessage("Check el net plz :)");
                mDialoge.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
                mDialoge.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject arg0, com.parse.ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

}

  public void update (View V){
    pd2.show();
    //update data in Parse

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> myQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestBosyApp");

    // Retrieve the object by id
    myQuery.getInBackground("U6Gwn2tiD8", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject testBosyApp, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //Initials our variables
                String companyName = etCompanyName.getText().toString().trim();
                String address = etAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                String numberOfEmployees = etNumberOfEmployees.getText().toString().trim();
                String contactNumber = etContactNumber.getText().toString().trim();

                //update it with new data

                testBosyApp.put("company_name", companyName);
                testBosyApp.put("address", address);
                testBosyApp.put("number_of_employees", numberOfEmployees);
                testBosyApp.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
                testBosyApp.saveInBackground();

                pd2.dismiss();

                AlertDialog.Builder mDialoge = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
                mDialoge.setTitle("2shta");
                mDialoge.setMessage("Keda eldata ra7t t2riban");
                mDialoge.setPositiveButton("cool", null);
                mDialoge.show();
            }else{
                pd2.dismiss();
                AlertDialog.Builder mDialoge = new   AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
                mDialoge.setTitle("Erorr");
                mDialoge.setMessage("Check el net plz :)");
                mDialoge.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
                mDialoge.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject arg0, com.parse.ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    });

}

 }
```

so what's the problem, progress-bar is loading without end and if I give progress-bar cancellation feature then put data in fields there's nothing happen .
plus if anyone have tutorials for use android with parse.com please provide me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Dude.. Sir? goto parse.com, there are tutorials.. you need to enable something <strike>i just do not remember</strike> Go to settings ->App Permissions ->Allow client class creation. Set it to ON> before you can send push from device and receive it.. also your manifest is not complete.. from what i know..

```
<application
android:name="com.example.mkadaimtwo.ParseCode"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

//edit started here
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

so copy and paste this manifest